# Relooking at this question with 20-20 hindsight, I think that the VTC was incorrect - what say you all?

Tags: discussion, close-reasons, closed-questions, vote-to-close

The question under consideration:

[Isn't Jesus's suffering over magnified by the Catholic Church?](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/29824/isnt-jesuss-suffering-over-magnified-by-the-catholic-church)

body as per:

> It seems too me that the suffering of Jesus is over magnified. I mean so many people have suffered tremendously for years. Like handicapped/sick people, prisoners, holocaust victims etc. I don't understand why to make so special and incredible suffering of one person who suffered just a few hours / days. I am honestly asking to understand, what makes people want to magnify that much the suffering of Jesus? I consider myself Jesus follower. Just I cannot understand this thing.

tags:  catholicism; jesus; suffering; historical-jesus;

It was closed as a duplicate with:

[How is Christ's death so significant?](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/2326/how-is-christs-death-so-significant)

It is true, that suffering is mentioned briefly in the body of this question and covered somewhat more extensively in the top voted answer, but in the other (9!) answers it is touched on either lightly or ignored - the overwhelming focus is on the significance of Christ's **death**.  To my mind there is a clear distinction between the concepts of suffering and death and the focuses of the two questions are definitely distinct.  Additionally, the closed question is scoped particularly for Catholicism - so why did it end up being closed as a duplicate and shouldn't in fact, be re-opened?

***Update:*** The title of the question has now been edited to: "Why is there such an emphasis on Jesus's suffering - particularly by the Catholic Church?"

Comment: I kind of agree that death and suffering are different in this context. I would favor a reopening and would suggest only the title is edited to something like "why is Christ's suffering so emphasized?"

Comment: @fredsbend thanks for your feedback

Answer (score 2):

It may have the wrong close reason, but it's still an opinion question and should remain closed.

Comment: Would an edit along the lines of: "What is the Catholic perspective on the the significance of Christ's suffering?" be sufficient to put it back on topic from your point of view?

Comment: @bruisedreed - Yes.